# List all outcomes from a list of strings with multiple occurrences based on weight limits

Tags: python-3.x

What I want to achieve is hard for me to explain so here's my analogy of what I'm after:

A commercial baker has 14.1kg of flour.

He has 4 items he can make.

```
item1 weighs 0.7kg, 

item2 weighs 1.3kg, 

item3 weighs 3.5kg, 

item4 weighs 7kg.
```

Using this we know that the possible amount of combinations this can be laid out linearly is 1600.

```
(14.1 // 0.7) * (14.1 // 1.3) * (14.1 // 3.5) * (14.1 // 7)
```

All of these would be left with leftover flour no matter what.
But out of those 1600 not all of them are valid in this situation as not all of the combinations <= 14.1kg so I can't use them..

What I want to do is use python to get all combinations of these items while remaining under 14.1g and return every outcome as well as a remainder.

I want it to look something like:

```
{item3, item3, item4} Leftovers: .1kg
{item2, item2, item2, item2, item4, item1} Leftovers: .6kg
# And keep listing all other outcomes under 14.1kg
```

Someone help please as this is frying my brain trying to get this to work as I'm not an expert at python nor am I at math.

Answer (score 0):

The most trivial solution would be the following:

```
products = [0.7, 1.3, 3.5, 7.0]
max_weight = 14
results = []

for num1 in range(int((max_weight // products[0]) + 1)):
    for num2 in range(int((max_weight // products[1]) + 1)):
        for num3 in range(int((max_weight // products[2]) + 1)):
            for num4 in range(int((max_weight // products[3]) + 1)):
                weight = num1 * products[0] + num2 * products[1] + num3 * products[2] + num4 * products[3]
                if weight < max_weight:
                    results.append((num1, num2, num3, num4, weight))

for result in results:
    print("{", end="")
    if result[0] > 0:
        print(", ".join(["item1"] * result[0]), end="")
    if result[1] > 0:
        print(", ", end="")
        print(", ".join(["item2"] * result[1]), end="")
    if result[2] > 0:
        print(", ", end="")
        print(", ".join(["item3"] * result[2]), end="")
    if result[3] > 0:
        print(", ", end="")
        print(", ".join(["item4"] * result[3]), end="")
    print("} ", end="")
    print("Leftovers: %0.1f" % (max_weight - result[4]))
```

Explanation:

The first section loops through the number of times we can choose each product. The minimum value is 0 and the maximum value (`int((max_weight // product[...]) + 1)`) is the number of times we can choose a product if we don't take anything else. We calculate the total weight and if it's lower than the maximum allowed then we store it:

```
for num1 in range(int((max_weight // products[0]) + 1)):
    for num2 in range(int((max_weight // products[1]) + 1)):
        for num3 in range(int((max_weight // products[2]) + 1)):
            for num4 in range(int((max_weight // products[3]) + 1)):
                weight = num1 * products[0] + num2 * products[1] + num3 * products[2] + num4 * products[3]
                if weight < max_weight:
                    results.append((num1, num2, num3, num4, weight))
```

The second section loops through the results and prints it in the format you provided. It won't print the product if we chose them 0 times. Lastly, it prints the leftover:

```
for result in results:
    print("{", end="")
    if result[0] > 0:
        print(", ".join(["item1"] * result[0]), end="")
    if result[1] > 0:
        print(", ", end="")
        print(", ".join(["item2"] * result[1]), end="")
    if result[2] > 0:
        print(", ", end="")
        print(", ".join(["item3"] * result[2]), end="")
    if result[3] > 0:
        print(", ", end="")
        print(", ".join(["item4"] * result[3]), end="")
    print("} ", end="")
    print("Leftovers: %0.1f" % (max_weight - result[4]))
```

Do note that this is the most naive solution. You can optimize it in a few ways, like jumping out of the loops if the total weight is already above the maximum.

Also, I didn't really understand what's the goal, but this solution will provide results where only half of the allowed weight is used. If you want to get the less `Leftover` then it's a harder problem ([Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem))